# How much higher accuracy of train than test is enough to consider the model overfitted?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, adaboost, ensemble-learning

Considering a dataset of 920 samples with 40 features in a binary classification problem. The dataset is the heart disease dataset publicly available here: archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/heart+Disease

I preprocessed the dataset discarding those features which contains >50% missing data. Those which contains < 50% I imputed it using MICE ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3074241. Then I bagged numerical data into categorical data by gathering the values in equal ranges and then encoding features by OHE. The info about the dataset is the following:

[image]

The models considered are:
Linear SVM, RBF SVM, Logistic Regression, KNN , Decision Tree , Random Forest

I tuned the parameters using RandomSearchCV:

```
> Model: SVC(C=0.1, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=0.1, kernel='linear',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)

> Model: SVC(C=10000.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=0.0001, kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)

> Model: LogisticRegression(C=0.01, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1, penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

> Model: KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=65, p=2,
           weights='uniform')

> Model: DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=10,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='random')

> Model: RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=30, max_features='sqrt', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=4, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=400, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
```

I got the following scores (mean +/- std) in a 10-CV: 
[image]

It surprises me that the training accuracy and F-score is higher (specially in random forest) than the test one.

Besides I computed bagging algorithms by the same methodology (tuning the number of estimators with RandomSearchCV and having the base_estimator the previous models considered):

```
Model: BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=SVC(C=0.1, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=0.1, kernel='linear',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False),
         bootstrap=True, bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0,
         max_samples=1.0, n_estimators=200, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False,
         random_state=36, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

Model: BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=SVC(C=10000.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=0.0001, kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False),
         bootstrap=True, bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0,
         max_samples=1.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False,
         random_state=37, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

Model: BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=LogisticRegression(C=0.01, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
          penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False),
         bootstrap=True, bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0,
         max_samples=1.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False,
         random_state=38, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

Model: BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=65, p=2,
           weights='uniform'),
         bootstrap=True, bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0,
         max_samples=1.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False,
         random_state=38, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

Model: BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=10,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='random'),
         bootstrap=True, bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0,
         max_samples=1.0, n_estimators=500, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False,
         random_state=34, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

Model: RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=30, max_features='sqrt', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=4, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=400, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
```

I got the following scores (mean +/- std) in a 10-CV:

[image]

It also surprises me that there is no so much improvement from single algorithms to bagged algorithms.

On the other hand I also tried AdaBoost with Decision Tree and Logistic Regression (same tuning of n_estimators and learning rate with Random SearchCV:

```
Model: AdaBoostClassifier(algorithm='SAMME.R',
          base_estimator=LogisticRegression(C=0.01, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
          penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False),
          learning_rate=10, n_estimators=600, random_state=38)

Model: AdaBoostClassifier(algorithm='SAMME.R',
          base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=10,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='random'),
          learning_rate=0.01, n_estimators=200, random_state=34)
```

I also got the following scores:

[image]

Reading about ensembles methods one may believe that its accuracy improves from single models, however for logistic regression even worsen (just a bit) but still, for Decision Trees it does not really improved that much < 1%.

What could have happened? Am I overfitting?

EDIT: 
As @Quickbeam2k1 pointed out, the one-hot-encoded groups DO NOT have the same number of data points. Stated another way, some of the groups are TOO small and hence they do not appear in the test set and the algorithm will fail to generalize well. See an example:

[image]

Besides, the some of the features are very unbalanced, in some cases there is just a couple of samples per feature. So I believe I need to discard some of the OHE Features. The thing is, which threshold should I consider to discard? I am thinking about discarding those features which percentage do not achieve 10% less than the proportional equal ratio of its values. Meaning that, if a feature, say chest pain, got 4 values, then there is cp_1, cp_2, cp_3, cp_4. If one of this OHE values got less than 25% - 10% (because there is 4 values, equal ratio is 25% per each value) = 15%. If a feature then do not achieve 15% of the samples within this feature, then discard it. Is that a good approach?

Furthermore, just as @HarisNadeem said, bagging algorithms aims to reduce variance of the data set. As I OneHotEncoded the features, I significantly reduced the dataset and thus it does not really improved the algorithms.

Comment: You should try reducing the number of features.  This is clearly overfitting.

Comment: also, check out https://stats.stackexchange.net and https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you try cross validation?

Comment: The features I am using are OneHotEncoded Features ie. if a feature got 4 values, then OHE gives 4 new features (0 or 1 depending whether or not the sample contains that feature). At the beginning I had 12 Features. @ChootsMagoots

Comment: Yes, it is 10 fold Cross Validation (10-CV) @HarisNadeem

Comment: Could you explain what type of data you are working on? For example text data or image data etc? Ensemble methods generally tend not to overfit (though there are most certainly cases and chances where it can happen).

Comment: It is the heart disease dataset publicly available here: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/heart+Disease

I preprocessed the dataset discarding those features which contains >50% missing data. Those which contains < 50% I imputed it using MICE https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3074241/, 
Then I bagged numerical data into categorical data by gathering the values in equal ranges and then encoding features by OHE.

Comment: Ok so I think I can answer one of your questions. Bagging leads to improvements for unstable procedures by reducing the variance from the data set, but since you grouped numerical data in equal ranges and turned it into categorical data, you have already significantly decreased the variance of your data set. Keep in mind, bagging can mildly degrade the performance of stable methods such as K-nearest neighbors.

Comment: another issue related to number of features: do all the one-hot encoded groups have the same number of data points? Approximately, you can punily have 22 data points per combination of one hot encoded values. How is the distribution of those combinations? It might be, the certain groups are too small (hence, they do not appear in the test set and an algorithm will fail to generalize well there)

Comment: See Edit @Quickbeam2k1 
Can I also mixed Categorical and numerical data and then see the performance of the algorithms? I mean, keeping the age, cholesterol and so on as they were without bagging them into ranges, then normalize them and see if it also improves. I OHE the features since I believe for some algorithms, when they compute the distance it will be biased from a continuous feature and OHE feature, so I wanted to keep them "standardized " in the same encoding

Comment: So based on your new edits, let me answer what I can. As for the point: *`Stated another way, some of the groups are TOO small and hence they do not appear in the test set and the algorithm will fail to generalize well.`* That is a problem of the data set, sadly, that just means you need to find a better way to enrich your data. If you have bad data or data lacking information, it is almost impossible to create strong results or inferences no matter how powerful your data set is. In ML your data is your fuel... Bad data=bad fuel. No matter how powerful your engine is

Comment: *`So I believe I need to discard some of the OHE Features. The thing is, which threshold should I consider to discard? I am thinking about discarding those features which percentage do not achieve 10% less than the proportional equal ratio of its values.`*
The problem with this approach is that you don't know how important those features are that you are discarding. For example, suppose there are only 4/100 cases where the chol level is super abnormal like 290 mg/dl. These would be a good indicator of heart disease in your ml but got discarded because they did not fit your threshhold of 10%

Comment: If you want to discard some of the OHE Features, that is not a bad idea but you do not want to use a threshold for that. Instead you want to use ML techniques known as [Dimensionality Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction#Kernel_PCA) specifically PCA. Though for your use case I would suggest using Kernel PCA as it seems to fit your data model more appropriately. I wont go into details of how PCA works but you can read it here: https://georgemdallas.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/principal-component-analysis-4-dummies-eigenvectors-eigenvalues-and-dimension-reduction/

Comment: I was running out of space which was getting ridiculous. Please let me know if you have any other questions. And do use the `@` symbol with my username, otherwise I don't get notifications. I almost overlooked your edits had I not been browsing through questions.